# how to encode returned response in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to encode one field from returned response. After sending an SMS using sms api, I got a response as below:

```
'{
    "ErrorCode":"000",
    "ErrorMessage":"Success",
    "JobId":"e51ca2d4-e3e6-415a-97f4-2e9a133f38e7",
    "MessageData":[
        {
            "Number":"91974ssdsd2",
            "MessageParts":[
                {
                    "MsgId":"91974ddddd-0fe367f3b1774e74bf7c06e21cf38482",
                    "PartId":1,
                    "Text":"The OTP for your login is uxlvRF"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```

I converted this response into following format:

```
'[
    "ErrorCode"=>"000",
    "ErrorMessage"=>"Success",
    "JobId"=>"e51ca2d4-e3e6-415a-97f4-2e9a133f38e7",
    "MessageData"=>[
        ["Number"=>"919747dddddd",
            "MessageParts"=>[
                [
                    "MsgId"=>"9197ddddd-0fe367f3b1774e74bf7c06e21cf38482",
                    "PartId"=>1,
                    "Text"=>"The OTP for your login is uxlvRF"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]'
```

this is done by using code: $triggersms is actual response

```
                $tgr_edt=str_replace(':', '=>', $triggersms);
                $tgr = str_replace('{', '[', $tgr_edt);
                $tgrnw = str_replace('}', ']', $tgr);
```

But i tried to use $tgrnw ['ErrorCode'] in my laravel code, It showed an error

"invalid offeset ErrorCode"..

Can anyone help??

Comment: inverted commas are not there... i just added just for the purpose of showing

Comment: Why not you do `json_decode` instead of `str_replace`  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance the response you received looks like JSON to me.

So do this:

```
$obj = json_decode($triggersms);
echo $obj->ErrorCode;
```

or

```
$array = json_decode($triggersms, true);
echo $array['ErrorCode'];
```

[You can read more about json_decode at the php.net manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)